# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: This operation may only be performed by the bucket owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-ami

Using the AWS s3api CLI, enable MFA Delete for the S3 buckets that fail this rule, for example:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket bucketname --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa "your-mfa-serial-number mfa-code"
```

> but getting this error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling
> the PutBucketVersioning operation: This operation may only be
> performed by the bucket owner.

Even I tried creating new bucket to do this but same error am getting. has anyone gone through this?

Answer (score 2):

Since its not specified in your question, I will assume a most likely scenario of not using a root account.

`MFA Delete` can be only enabled by the **root** of your account ([from docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete)):

> The bucket owner, the AWS account that created the bucket (root account), and all authorized IAM users can enable versioning, but **only the bucket owner (root account) can enable MFA Delete**.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete) it states you **must be the root user to enable this**.

> The bucket owner, the AWS account that created the bucket (root account), and all authorized IAM users can enable versioning, but **only the bucket owner (root account) can enable MFA Delete**.

Other than this any other `BucketVersioning` configuration can be completed by the root user or a permitted IAM user/role.

This tries to prevent an employee accidently enabling the feature because they have too many permissions.

As a warning if you're configuring this via the CLI, **do not leave root IAM credentials** after the action has been taken.